# jquery tabs dissapear when re-clicked

Tags: jquery, tabs

Here is my test page (dont mind the layout right now)

https://www.bcidaho.com/test_kalyani/employer-plans-test.asp

i found something weird.  if you click back and forth between tab 1 and tab 2, its fine.

if you click tab 3, and got to another tab, the content dissapears... and i can not figure out why???

I am boggled, and can not figure out why it does this.... is it a display:hide element in the CSS?

here is a link to the CSS file: https://www.bcidaho.com/css/employer.css

here is a link to the javascript files that i use:
https://www.bcidaho.com/js/ui.toggle-employers.js
https://www.bcidaho.com/js/tabbed-menu3.js

Comment: I'm not sure what the bug is but you could clean things up a lot and hopefully fix it or discover it. e.g. the [current tab index](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#...retrieve_the_index_of_the_currently_selected_tab) can be found with `var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');`. Additionally, you can clean up a lot of `.parent().parent()...` code with [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/). It's clearer, and more robust. Actually, all that class manipulation to show/hide content is really unnecessary--that's what the plugin is for :).

Comment: If you have access to those divs I would give them an ID attribute that way you can access them and change their class ...

$('#tab1').addClass(...) etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The way I see you are setting display for these tabs is via:**

```
tab1: <div class="current"..
tab2: <div class="tab "..
tab3: <div class="tab "..
```

**When you click on tab 2 it changes to**

```
tab1: <div class="tab"..
tab2: <div class="tab current" ...
tab3: <div class="tab" ...
```

**When you click back on tab 1 it changes to**

```
tab1: <div class="tab current "...
tab2: <div class="tab" ...
tab3: <div class="tab" ...
```

**But when you click on tab 3 I see:**

```
tab1: <div clas="tab" ...
tab2: <div class="tab" ...
tab3: <div class="tab" ...
```

So I suspect that what is going on is that you need to make sure that when tab three i clicked that the **"current" class** is **removed** from the prior **current class** and then "**added**" to tab 3:

Comment: and i use this set up on another page with 5 tabs, and it works fine... this is freaking killing me.

Comment: I think something is going wrong with the part of the code that has the **.parent().parent()...** If I were you I would add **id attributes** to those bits and then select for via id selector **$('#idname')...**

Comment: check this... when just strip all of teh content out of the TABS, and just put in the text ONE in tab 1, and TWO in tab 2, and THREE in tab 3, it works fine... WTF?!?!  could it be an unclosed div somewhere thats not setting the DIV to "tab current" somehow?

Comment: damn it... it was a freaking unclosed tag in the content.

sorry to be sucha  noob.